# Deleting from S3 with iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ios9

I'm trying to delete an object from an S3 bucket with the AWS iOS SDK:

```
AWSS3DeleteObjectRequest *deleteObjectRequest = [AWSS3DeleteObjectRequest new];
deleteObjectRequest.bucket = kAmazonBucketName;
deleteObjectRequest.key = thumbnailFileName;

AWSS3 *s3 = [AWSS3 defaultS3];

[[s3 deleteObject:deleteObjectRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
    NSError *error = task.error;
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"[AmazonAPIClient] Error deleting photo: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        if (completion)
            completion(NO);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"[AmazonAPIClient] Photo deleted");
    }
}
```

The code runs and I see the success message, but if I search my S3 bucket through the AWS web dashboard, I find the file still there.

How can I delete files from the bucket in iOS?

Note that my bucket has Read/Write/Delete permissions granted to "Everyone".

Comment: Can you print out `task.result` to make sure the call actually succeeded? Also, when [Versioning](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html) is enabled, Amazon S3 does not delete an object.

Comment: Versioning is disabled. The output is `<AWSS3DeleteObjectOutput: 0x137cbc800>`. Not sure what to do with that, the properties listed in the API don't exist on the object

Comment: [Enabling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html#logging) the verbose logging may help.

Comment: make sure the "key" path exactly to your folder (if exist folder path)